# Javascript Add new element to array of elements if not exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reduce

I have an array like:

```
 [{"x": 2020-06-27T08:00:00.000Z, "y": 33},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T10:00:00.000Z, "y": 500},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T12:00:00.000Z, "y": 98},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T14:00:00.000Z, "y": 344},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z, "y": 1}]
```

The array is pre-sorted already from earliest to latest. What I need to do, is to through the 'x' of array (which is a date), and check if some even hour(like 0,2,4.. or 22) is not there, and if not, add new entry with that hour 'x' in a date and 'y' value equal to zero.

Is there any efficient way to that?
In the end, array should look something like:

```
[{"x": 2020-06-27T00:00:00.000Z, "y": 0},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T02:00:00.000Z, "y": 0},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T04:00:00.000Z, "y": 0},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T06:00:00.000Z, "y": 0},
 {"x": 2020-06-27T08:00:00.000Z, "y": 33}, 
 {"x": 2020-06-27T10:00:00.000Z, "y": 500}]
```

and so on,

Comment: I will suggest to convert the array to an object with the dates as keys, or have the dates and 'y' values in two different arrays.

Comment: If you stick with array instead of object, you need to iterate to check if the `x` exists or not. To do so, you could use binary-search since your array is sorted.

Comment: are you checking for a single value, or for all instances where an even hours is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use moment lib to generate all time schedules, then use map function to transfer the array.

```js
var start = moment.utc("2020-06-27").startOf('day'); 
var end = moment.utc("2020-06-27").endOf('day'); 

const origArray = [{"x": "2020-06-27T08:00:00.000Z", "y": 33},{"x": "2020-06-27T10:00:00.000Z", "y": 500},{"x": "2020-06-27T12:00:00.000Z", "y": 98},{"x": "2020-06-27T14:00:00.000Z", "y": 344},{"x": "2020-06-27T22:00:00.000Z", "y": 1}]

const schedulesArray = []
let currentTime = start
while (currentTime.isBefore(end)){
    schedulesArray.push(currentTime.toISOString())
  currentTime = currentTime.add(2, 'hours')
}
const newArray = schedulesArray.map(t => {
    const existingOrig = origArray.filter(o => o.x === t)
  if(existingOrig.length > 0){
    return JSON.stringify(existingOrig[0])
  }else{
    const newObj = {}
    newObj.x = t
    newObj.y = 0
    return JSON.stringify(newObj)
  }
});

console.log('arr ' + newArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```